# Matrix, plus symbol in text input breaking in simple if conditional

Tags: matrix

I seem to be getting the same error [as in this post](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/matrix-user-global-variables-in-basic-text-input-breaking-in-simple-if-conditio), but in my case the problematic part of my condition is a plus symbol, which is pretty absurd!

```
{if '{caption}' != ''}data-caption="#caption-{row_id}"{/if}
```

In this case, if the caption includes a plus, it will result in:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /Users/danielhowells/Sites/Calvert/www.calvertadmin.com/web/content/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(683) : eval()'d code on line 28
```

It's a bit embarrassing explaining to my client that they can't use + in their captions. :-)

Comment: Try without quoting and bracing your conditional, please? ie: {if caption != ""}code{/if}  Also, knowing your version for both EE and Matrix would help out here.  Thank you!

Comment: I tried that already - no dice. EE version v2.5.5 and Matrix 2.5.3

Comment: Hi, Daniel - I can't reproduce this.  I have an entry with a title Plus Sign, and I an RTE field, and in that I included a + sign.  I then have this: {exp:channel:entries channel="pt_test_channel" limit="1"}
<h1>{title}</h1>
{pt_matrix}{matrix_cell_2} 
{if matrix_cell_2 != ""}{row_id} not empty{/if}
{/pt_matrix}
{/exp:channel:entries} and it outputs "12 not empty" on the front end, no parse errors.  Can you post the rest of your template code please?

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this - seems to be okay with 2.5.5 so let's close this for now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [low replace](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-replace) on the tag and turn the + into a  word:

```
{if '{exp:low_replace find="+" replace="plus"}{caption}{/exp:low_replace}' != ''}
```